# Get value from a dropdown list and insert it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hello I have a drop down list with options that a get from a table in my database and I want when the user select on of the options to store it in another table of the database. I have the code for the select by a cant find the way to get the correct value in order to store. 
Here is the code for the drop down list ...

```
<select id="SelectDisease" name="disease">
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM disease");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<option value=$disease>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

And here is the insert into code ...

```
queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient (fname,lname,username,email,password,gender,age,disease,spid) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email', '$password','$PatientG','$PatientAge','$disease','$PatientSPID')");
                die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.<br /><br />");
```

Comment: Is this inside a form tag?
If so, try to get the value selected using $_POST['disease'].

Comment: `"<option value=$disease>"` May be missing the quotes around `value=""` and where is $disease defined.

Comment: @TimLewis it is not this because if i did like you said it stores nothing in the specific column of the table

Comment: @NickBourlai What I mean is `$disease` is undefined in the current code snippet. Unless you define it somewhere else.

Comment: @ElefantPhace can you be more clear in your answer please, you mean something like that "<option value=$_POST['disease']" ???

Comment: @TimLewis yes it is defined

Comment: @NickBourlai Ok, where? Right now, if you have `$disease` defined, every option is going to have the same value. Is that what you want??

Comment: You probably want to use `$row['name']` as the value for your option. And be sure to wrap it in quotes

Comment: @TimLewis no it is not going to have the same value, the value will change depending on the selected option

Comment: @NickBourlai Ugh I know that. But when you **create** your select input, you're using a defined `$disease` for **every** option. Where is that defined? And why do you think it will change during the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a mess, so this might be a messy post, but I'll try to clarify what I think you're trying to do. For your select input:

```
<select id="SelectDisease" name="disease">
<?php
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM disease");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

That way, your select's options each have a different value, and not `$disease`, whatever that equated to.

Next, where you process your `POST` request:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
... // Etc for each input you have.
$disease = $_POST['disease'];
```

Then your query should work correctly:

```
queryMysql("INSERT INTO patient 
(fname,lname,username,email,password,gender,age,disease,spid) 
VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email', '$password','$PatientG','$PatientAge','$disease','$PatientSPID')");
```

If that doesn't work, comment with any errors and we'll try to sort them out.

**NOTE**

This is **INCREDIBLY** insecure. I would never recommend doing this on a live application, as SQL Injections would be quite easy. Also, please note that MySQL functions are being deprecated. Look up **MySQLi** or **PDO** and learn to implement those.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is a method:

1. Include the `<select/>` tag within a `<form/>` tag with an `action` to another PHP page.
2. In the second PHP page, read the variable out `$disease = $_POST['disease']`
3. Call your SQL Insert Statement

Side Note:

Perhaps change:

```
echo "<option value=$disease>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: I have the form tags and also i read the variable and still doesnt work

Comment: Do you have METHOD="POST" in your form tag?

Comment: yes i just dont want to post the whole code in the question ... it gives me this error ( syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting )

Comment: That's because he didn't escape the double quotes. If you used a syntax highlighting editor you'd easily see that.

Comment: Sorry, I made some syntax errors as @ElefantPhace said. Try again.

Comment: cant find it because it shows me the line of code that gives the error and it is the code that you write and when i check the quotes it looks that they are ok